# How to set allow-access-origin in AJAX header?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

How to set header for allow-access-origin for AJAX request using JSON, JQUERY?

Comment: We'll need more info here. What exactly is the error you're running into, what have you tried (sample code). From this it's not even clear if you're talking about a request or a response.

Comment: Not an elaborate question. Please rephrase your question. It is not clear about what are you talking about is it request or response? What all issues are you facing and what all steps are you taking ?

Comment: Thanks Bagley and Samarth for your interest to help me. I have tried to call JSON data using AJAX call in javascript. Problem is that, I am getting this error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the endpoint supports `jsonp`, remove `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error by modifying the dataType parameter to `dataType:'jsonp'` and adding a `crossDomain:true`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com?request='+key,
    data: myData,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

Comment: This makes a big assumption that the endpoint supports `jsonp` which is often not the case

Comment: @Iman Hejazi, Thanks for your ajax method you mentioned. Could you clarify what did you mean by setHeader? I have tried using datatype: 'JSONP' but, I got unexpected syntax error, unexpected token : , though I got desired data in console in JSON format. It seems to me that response data is JSON in name:value format. So, I am getting this error.